# Deploying a nodejs app with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a nodejs app running on port 8081:

```
http://mysite.com:8081/
```

I want to access it simply by going to `http://mysite.com/` so I setup a virtual host with expressjs:

```
app.use(express.vhost('yugentext.com', app));
```

That seems too easy, and it doesn't work. Am I confused about how expressjs vhosts work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do these via express well, the problem comes from your **dns setup**, not from the express code.

Add an `A entry` to your domain like these:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost *.mysite.com *.www.mysite.com
```

You should wait to the DNS propagation. (from seconds to hours).

If apache or other web server is running any vhost on port 80 there will be conflicts.

**And the other way:**

nodejs and express are far away from the performance offered by apache and **nginx**  (vhost/proxy stuff).

Nginx>Apache (fits better with nodejs)

Creates a proxy from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com:8080`

On these way nodejs and express handles the ui, methods, httpserver etc, and Nginx or Apache the proxy , vhost, and managing your static assets sooo fast.

check these config here: [Trouble with Nginx and Multiple Meteor/Nodejs Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283045/trouble-with-nginx-and-multiple-meteor-nodejs-apps/)

Comment: I also run rails apps off this server on port 80, what's my best bet in terms of speed?

Comment: Here you go: [USING NGINX TO AVOID NODE.JS LOAD](http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load/). So good article.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing  `app.listen(8081)`. You should be doing `app.listen(80)`. I have no experience with  express vhosts, but you don't need them for this simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream node-apps {
  server host_ip_1:3000;
  server host_ip_2:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_pass http://node-apps/;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

this is my nginx config, proxy pass multiple servers, good luck :p