# Add a static frontpage to Meteor.js

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've started learning Meteor.js and it seems fabulous for single page app. But I only know how to create one page for the entire site.

How can I add a static page to `http://domain.com` and have my Meteor app run at `http://domain.com/app`? For your solution, will your page actually change when you go to `domain.com/app` from `domain.com`?

Comment: You may also be able to use apache, ngenx, or some other http server to do what you want.  Which http server would you choose if you were hosting a static page?  Hosting static page at domain.com and meteor app at app.domain.com is very straightforward.

Comment: I will choose either nginx and apache to host the static pages. How should it be configured in these cases?

Comment: if you are undecided, go with ngenx since it supports websockets.  Get your static site working on ngenx. Then follow [instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14976998/728291) to add proxy to the meteor app running on a separate port and accessible by subdomain.

Comment: more examples - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16283045/728291), [here](https://gist.github.com/joemccann/644282)

Comment: Sorry for typos on Nginx.  At least I was consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). It lets you assign routes to templates.

Comment: While not released yet, you should be aware of `meteor-iron-router`, a far more flexible router that is being worked on by both people that worked on the past meteor routers.

Comment: iron router ftw. use that.

Comment: As of June 2015, [flow-router](https://forums.meteor.com/t/should-i-be-using-iron-router-or-is-it-dying/4540) is starting to be preferred vs. iron-router.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind calling a html file you can have static pages in /public. This probably wont work for you, because your page probably isnt actually a "static" page. This would be accessed at http://mydomain.com/index.html .

eg, 
/public/index.html  :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/public/index.css rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="something"> I am a web page </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```